# The formatting of your code differs from the recommendation - I AM NEW its why im here

Tags: python

Here is the exercise:
A right triangle has one angle of 90°
A obtuse triangle has one angle of more than 90°
A triangle is acute if all three angles are less than 90°

Write a program that asks the user for the values of three angles in degrees. First check if the entered values are valid. The values are only valid if they are >0 and if their sum is 180°. If the entered values are valid, classify the triangle as right, acute or obtuse.

Below are two example executions of the program with invalid values:
Please enter the first angle: 60
Please enter the second angle: 60
Please enter the third angle: 100
The entered values are not valid.

Please enter the first angle: 200
Please enter the second angle: -10
Please enter the third angle: -10
Angles smaller than 0 are not valid

Please enter the first angle: 60
Please enter the second angle: 30
Please enter the third angle: 90
The triangle is a right triangle.

I keep getting these refactor messages: chained-comparison: Simplify chained comparison between the operands (exercise.py: 11)

```
a = int(input("Please enter the first angle: "))
b = int(input("Please enter the second angle: "))
c = int(input("Please enter the third angle: "))

if ((a + b + c) or (a == 0) or (b == 0) or (c == 0)):
    print("The entered values are not valid.")
elif a < 90 and b < 90 and c < 90:
  print("acute angle")
elif (a == 180) or (b == 180) or (c == 180):
    print("obtuse angle")
elif (a >= 200 and a <= 180) or (b <= -10) or (c <= -10):
    print("Angles smaller than 0 are not valid.")
elif (total == 180 and a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0):
    print("The triangle is a right triangle.")
```

Comment: if any of your angles = 180 then you don't have a triangle.  and why are you testing if b or c <= -10?

Comment: I have edited my post to make sense of my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a combination of overthinking the problem and being very new to programming.  First, you should write out your logic clearly so you can understand it.  Then you translate it to code.

```
If any input <= 0:
    Not a triangle
Else if total of inputs != 180:
    Not a triangle
Else if any input == 90:
    Right triangle
Else if any input > 90:
    Obtuse triangle
Else
    Acute triangle
```

Now see if you can convert that to python without thinking about the specific example values you were given.  Those values are used to test your logic, not to define it.

Comment: You're not wrong there. I am VERY new. I am on my Week 1 with Python training. And Im not smug about it. I have been struggling to understand it.

Comment: I made a mistake on the obtuse condition, accidentally said > 180 instead of > 90.  I have corrected it

Comment: Oooh awesome. We are using CodeOcean to test our codes. So, that's why the inputs are very specifics because the system is looking for that -- if that make sense. But i totally get that simplified codes.

Answer (score 0):

In Python:

```
a >= 200 and a <= 180
```

can be written as

```
180 <= a <= 200
```

You can see the docs [comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) for more details.

Comment: can it though?  what number is both >=200 AND <= 180?

Comment: Thank you. But its still telling that the output is not correct for the last one: elif (total == 180 and a > 0 and b > 0 and c > 0): print("The triangle is a right triangle.")

I couldn't get that to work. It's giving me the output message from the first "if"; The entered values are not valid

Comment: @AnnaMontes as long as (a + b + c) is something other than zero, the code will always go into the first "if".  Try `(a + b + c) != 180`

Comment: @kurt Thanks Kurt. So, you mean to say, my (a + b + c) is incorrect? Coz I really need to print the other message that are required but I just couldn't make it to work :(

Okay ill try that (a + b + c) != 180

Comment: there are other issues as well, but that's the first one

Comment: @Kurt okay that one worked. Now, its giving me a problem with Obtuse triangle :D